# Weird behaviour when customising views-view-unformatted.html.twig with grouping

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to override the views-view-unformatted.html.twig template by an unformatted view that includes a hidden Grouping field.

The default template includes this code:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3 class="group-title">{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I copy the default template into my theme, this generates the results I would expect:

[image]

When I try to modify the code by wrapping a div around the loop that fetches the rows, like this:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3 class="group-title">{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
<div class="group-content">
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I get this output instead:

[image]

Note that the first two rows are wrapped in the **group-content** div, whilst the third row is now wrapped in a *separate* group-content div. There should obviously be only one group-content div, with all rows inside it.

My goal in overriding the default template is to put them all in a separate div, which I can't do from within the views settings, so the fact that overriding the template isn't working defeats the object of the exercise.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how to get around it?

Comment: The template looks correct. The screenshots are from the browser developer console though. Browsers fix invalid HTML source (e.g. a missing closing tag) by themselves, so the markup you are seeing there is not the real, rendered one. Check the real, unformatted source code (Ctrl+U in Chrome), I guess there is wrong markup in one of the inner, nested template files.

Comment: If you turn twig debugging on (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) then you should be able to see where the broken HTML is coming from if you look at the source of your page carefully.

Comment: Did you check tag div in your template? I saw missing closing tag div after {% endfor %}

Comment: Well spotted! Last '<div>' should be '</div>'.

Comment: Sorry - the closing <div> was a typo in the post, not the template. I've corrected it in the post.

Comment: I've checked the unformatted code, and the second group-content div is definitely being inserted when I enable the template. The only difference between scenario 1 and 2 is the additional group-content div. Could it be there is a bug in the source template?

Answer (score 2):

count opening and closing tag `div`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thanks to everyone who commented. Turns out the issue was that one node being returned in the view didn't have the grouping field set. This only became a problem once I added the extra div around the rows output.